# Any reference / book on setting up Jetty on Linux box?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, jetty

I have purchased a vps system recently for Java web development recently. However, I need to setup everything, configure apache, email etc. Are there any guide/reference book I can study to get these works done? I am going to install Jetty on Linux box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Jetty is very simple to get up and running AFTER you get Java installed.

Download the distribution and unpack it.  Inside is a start.jar file which you invoke with "java -jar start.jar".

Answer (score 1):

To install Jetty I used:

```
$ wget http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6.1.24/jetty-6.1.24.zip
$ unzip jetty-6.1.24.zip
$ cp -R jetty-6.1.24 /opt/
$ cd /opt
$ ln -s /opt/jetty-6.1.24 jetty
```

To Run:

```
$ cd /opt/jetty
$ java -jar start.jar etc/jetty.xml
```

Then open `http://localhost:8080/`